# How to notify or send acknowledgement to user that he/she is registered or not without email

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a college alumni system that manages alumni. Admin sends the acknowledgment to a person who has done registration. And after registration, the request goes to admin if the admin allows then that person can log in.

But how do send an acknowledgment that the request has been approved or denied without email, I'm using the old version of wamp and PHP and I don't have enough time to install the new one due to the submission date.

Comment: Can you not just display a message with the request status when the user tried to log in? You could send a message via SMS but if you can't use email I doubt it's an option for you. You could perhaps use Google Firebase to send a push notification to the browser?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Andrew thank you so much for helping out. I think the message while logging in will work best for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot send an email, here are some options to communicate the acknowledgment to the user:

- Display a message to the user when they attempt to log in
- Send an SMS message
- Use a push notification service such as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)